# combine multiple list to single array

Tags: javascript, typescript

`{ "data": [ {"firstName": "Achmad"}, {"lastName": "a"} ] }` and this my script `var body = request.body;for(var i = 0;i < body.data.length;i++){var obj = body.data[i];var keyes = Object.keys(obj);}` the problem response from `var keyes = Object.keys(obj);` is list like this `[ 'firstName' ] [ 'lastName' ]` i'm wanna like this `['firstName', 'lastName']`

Thanks before.

Comment: But what is that "list" ? Could you add some sample data and what you've tried to format it differently?

Comment: You have to initialize and build up your array object.  This should be easily solvable by some google searching.

Comment: You should check this method : [Array.concat(Array)](https://howchoo.com/g/mzbmyzi2zda/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript#arrayconcat)

Comment: the request body like this `{
 "data": [
  {"firstName": "Achmad"}, {"lastName": "a"}
 ]
}` and this my script `var body = request.body;for(var i = 0;i < body.data.length;i++){var obj = body.data[i];var keyes = Object.keys(obj);}` the problem response from `var keyes = Object.keys(obj);` is list like this `[ 'firstName' ]
[ 'lastName' ]` i'm wanna like this `['firstName', 'lastName']`

Comment: This is horrendous - you should put some effort into how you pose your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each of the arrays are elements of a parent array, one way you could achieve this is by using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const flat = [
  ["aku"],
  ["dia"],
  ["ia"]
].reduce((accum, el) => accum.concat(el), [])

console.log(flat);
```

Comment: the request body like this `{
 "data": [
  {"firstName": "Achmad"}, {"lastName": "a"}
 ]
}` and this my script `var body = request.body;for(var i = 0;i < body.data.length;i++){var obj = body.data[i];var keyes = Object.keys(obj);}` the problem response from` var keyes = Object.keys(obj);` is list like this `[ 'firstName' ]
[ 'lastName' ]` i'm wanna like this `['firstName', 'lastName']`

Comment: @AlmostHandsome Whoops, you are right. Updated the code.

Comment: @Ahmed - You most definitely want to edit your question instead of posting important details in a random comment.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**: You could `concat` each item of your array :

```
const body = {
  "data": [
    {"firstName": "Achmad"},
    {"lastName": "a"}
  ]
};

let result = [];
for (item of body.data) {
  result = result.concat(Object.keys(item));
}

console.log(result); // -> ['firstName', 'lastName']
```

Comment: the request body like this `{
 "data": [
  {"firstName": "Achmad"}, {"lastName": "a"}
 ]
}` and this my script `var body = request.body;for(var i = 0;i < body.data.length;i++){var obj = body.data[i];var keyes = Object.keys(obj);}` the problem response from `var keyes = Object.keys(obj);` is list like this `[ 'firstName' ]
[ 'lastName' ]` i'm wanna like this `['firstName', 'lastName']`

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you want to do something like this

```
var body = request.body;
var keyes = [];
for(var i = 0; i < body.data.length; i++){
    var obj = body.data[i];
    keyes.push( Object.keys(obj) );
}
```

Comment: the request body like this `{
 "data": [
  {"firstName": "Achmad"}, {"lastName": "a"}
 ]
}` and this my script `var body = request.body;for(var i = 0;i < body.data.length;i++){var obj = body.data[i];var keyes = Object.keys(obj);}` the problem response from `var keyes = Object.keys(obj);` is list like this `[ 'firstName' ]
[ 'lastName' ]` i'm wanna like this `['firstName', 'lastName']`

Comment: define ```keys``` variable as an array outside of the loop and inside the loop push the data in it.

Comment: could you give some example?

Comment: after i'm corrected your answer code in there i'm getting `[ [ 'firstName' ] ]
[ [ 'firstName' ], [ 'lastName' ] ]` why not `[ [ 'firstName' ], [ 'lastName' ] ]` ?

Comment: @Ahmed because the OP's code doesn't do what you want. Use `Array.prototype.concat` or for es2018 use `Array.prototype.flatten`. The OP hilariously managed to make their code even **more** wrong after the edit